# How to set major locator of secondary axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to set a major locator for a secondary axis with 24 hour intervals, but it’s not valid and does not result in any errors.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

dt=pd.DataFrame({'time':[100000,200000,500000,800000],'value':[1,2,4,6]})
plot= plt.subplot()
plot.plot(dt.time,dt.value)
x_major_locator=plt.MultipleLocator(100000)
plot.xaxis.set_major_locator(x_major_locator)
plot.set_xlabel("Second")

s2h=lambda s: s/3600
h2s=lambda h: h*3600
ax2=plot.secondary_xaxis("top",functions=(s2h,h2s))
x_major_locator=plt.MultipleLocator(24)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(x_major_locator)
ax2.set_xlabel("Hour")
plt.show()
```

Comment: What error message do you get? I get a syntax error, then after correcting it another error since you should be using `plt` not `plot` for several lines.

Comment: @BenT - yeah, there's the missing `:` after `'time'` and then `plot.show()` should be `plt.show()`, but regardless, after fixing those two the resulting [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIA58.png) doesn't have the multiple locator as desired. I'm guessing that the fix will be to use `Axes.twiny` but haven't gotten a successful result yet

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why the ticks are not being modified; however, one way to get around this is to create a new subplot axis that shares `y`. The following will work as long as you do not change the limits because the lines are plotted over each other. If do need to change the limits, then you can do a hacky approach by plotting the line in negative `y` space and setting the `ylims` which will preserve your top x-axis.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

dt=pd.DataFrame({'time':[100000,200000,500000,800000],'value':[1,2,4,6]})
plot= plt.subplot()
plot.plot(dt.time,dt.value)
x_major_locator=MultipleLocator(100000)
plot.xaxis.set_major_locator(x_major_locator)
plot.set_xlabel("Second")

s2h=lambda s: s/3600

h2s=lambda h: h*3600

#ax2=plot.secondary_xaxis("top",functions=(s2h,h2s))
ax2 = plot.twiny()
ax2.plot(s2h(dt.time),dt.value)



x_major_locator = MultipleLocator(24)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(x_major_locator)
ax2.set_xlabel("Hour")

#ax2.set_xlim(0,200) #If you do this, you get 2 lines

plt.show()
```

[image]